# d3 js highlight nodes containing given string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, d3.js

I'm willing to search and highlight nodes which are containing given string.
[sample](https://jsbin.com/wudafuburo/1/edit?js,output)

For that i'm calling set_focus method

```
function set_focus(d)
{   
    text.style("opacity", function(o) {
        return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : null;
    });

    img.style("opacity", function(o) {
        return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : null;
    });

    link.style("opacity", function(o) {
        return o.source.index == d.index || o.target.index == d.index ? 1 : null;
    }); 

}
```

Above function is conditionally setting opacity of elements. I want to set the opacity of nodes which are connected with each other. But i don't want to disturb the opacity of those nodes which are not connected.

For more clarification:

```
return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : null;
```

I don't want to return opacity if `isConnected == false`

**Required:** `return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : "here return the current opacity value";`

**Happening:** `return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : "returning zero or null";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the opacity value of the current element with a **getter**:

```
d3.select(this).style("opacity");
```

Then, you can use it in your ternary operator:

```
text.style("opacity", function(o) {
    var current =  d3.select(this).style("opacity");
    return isConnected(d.id, o.id) ? 1 : current;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, I've tried what you said...but var current =  d3.select(this).attr("opacity"); is returning null. Do i need to set the opacity of text at the time of creating it?

Comment: Ok got it , var current =  d3.select(this).style("opacity"); replacing attr with style.... Thank You !